# Segmentation fault: 11 while copying one array to another

Tags: c, arrays

I want to copy all the contents from `buf[rm]` to `temp_a` and print `temp_a` but getting Segmentation fault: 11 after running. I need to use `key[]` further in program.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main()
    {
        int c = 0, rm;
        int i;
        int iter;
        int j = 0;
        int temp;
        int temp_a;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            char buf[32];

            for (int rm = 0; rm < 32; rm++)
            {
                buf[rm] = rand();

                strcpy(temp_a,buf[rm]);
                key[] = temp_a;
                printf("%d\n",key[] );

}

    }
}
```

Comment: temp_a is not a pointer.

Comment: Why are you declaring variables in your loops?

Comment: How does `key[]` even compile?

Comment: You are changing your code on the fly here. So which code are you *really* complaining about?

Comment: nope just initialized variables outside the loop

Comment: Why are you passing two ints to `strcpy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `int temp_a;` so `temp_a` is a `int` variable with fix size and you are trying to copy a string into it. Read all the data types in C and understand properly before starts coding. Also read about array and how they are different from other variable type. You have to declare your `temp_a` variable as `char temp_a[32];` or dynamic memory allocation like `char *temp_a = malloc(32);`

You need below modification:-

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
        int buf[32];// this should be a int array

        for (int rm = 0; rm < 32; rm++)
        {
            buf[rm] = rand();// rand returns integer 
            temp_a = buf[rm]);
            key[rm] = temp_a;
            printf("%d\n",key[rm] );

        }
    }
```

Comment: I know I need to work on fundamentals, here I need to copy `buf[rm]` content into `temp_a` and allocate `temp_a` to key[] array so that I can use it further in code

Comment: You don't need to angry on me. I am just giving you advise and trying to help you here. you can do it by following my example.

Comment: I thought you are angry.

Comment: `buf[rm] = rand();
             strcpy(temp_a,buf[rm]);
             strcpy(key,temp_a);` still same error

Comment: No not at all I am not angry at all. We are here to help you people. I have modified your answer. Now try.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, lots wrong going on here.

The function strcpy is to copy a terminated string to a buffer location. You specify an int temp_a as the destination, so the maximum chars that will fit is 4. However, you declare buf[32] as uninitialised, and strcpy requires a terminated string as the source. The function fails to find a terminating character so it just writes past the bounds of temp_a.

Comment: Since OP did not pass in the address of `temp_a`, but rather the value, it is even worse.  It is instead being copied to some random location (based on the uninitialized contents of `temp_a`).

Answer (score 1):

You do not have enough memory "allocated" for the entry you are trying to allocate to key[]. Mind you, you need to tell the compiler what kind of data(memory size) should be prepared before-hand. Segmentation errors tell you that you are trying to fit in data where there is no enough memory reserved.

According to the data ypu want to assign, malloc() in this case will help you to reserve the necessary memory to reserve if you are looking for efficiency. Otherwise, you need to declare the equivalent array to store all your entries.